# question about connected sets

Tags: real-analysis, connectedness

Suppose both $A_1 \cup A_2$ and $A_1 \cap A_2$ are connected. Show that

a) If $A_1$ and $A_2$ are closed then $A_1$ and $A_2$ are connected.

b) if one of $A_1$ or $A_2$ is not closed, then $A_1$ or $A_2$ may be disconnected.

Here is what I got so far.

Supposed that both $A_1 \cup A_2$ and $A_1 \cap A_2$ are connected, and $A_1$ and $A_2$ are closed. Assume the contrary that $A_1 $ is disconnected. Then there exist 2 non-empty disjoint open set $B_1$ and $C_1$ such that 
$$A_1 \subset B_1 \cup C_1$$

Thus 
$$A_1 \cup A_2=B_1 \cup C_1 \cup A_2$$

since $B_1 \cap C_1 =\emptyset$, $A_1 \cap A_2= A_2 \cap B_1 \cup A_2 \cap C_1$ is disconnected, contradict to the assumption that it's connected. We cna use similar argument for $A_2$ . the thing that concern me is I don't use any from the fact that $A_1$ and $A_2$ are closed. So I got the feeling that my argument is not correct. For part b), I'm not sure where to start, should I find an example?

Comment: You are right, $B_1 \cap C_1=\emptyset$, but we don't know whether$B_1$ intersect $A_2$ or not. I need to rework on that part too. Thanks.

Comment: I fix my argument for part a), is it look better now, but I still didn't use the fact that both $A_1$ and $A_2$ are closed

Comment: Look at my new counter example, when I typed the previous one, I forgot to add an interval. Also see how it can relate to your proof. $A_1 = [0,1)\cup (1,2]$ and $A_2 = \{1\}$.

Comment: From your example, I can see that $B_1 =[0,1)$ , $C_1=(1,2]$, which are disjoint and non-empty, so $A_1$ is disconnected, just like my assumption, $A_1 \cup A_2=[0,2]$ which is connected but $A_1 \cap A_2= \emptyset$ which is diconnected and lead to contradiction, so my argument was correct without using the closeness.

Comment: Could you find the reference that empty set is disconnected?

Comment: $\emptyset = \emptyset  \cup \emptyset$ which is the union of 2 open sets, and $\emptyset \cap \emptyset =\emptyset$ they are disjoint :D I know this sound a little bit crazy, but that is how I understand the concept, please correct me if I'm worng :)

Comment: I believe the empty set is connected by definition, since it can not be written as two non empty separated sets.

Comment: I believe you, even I feel my argument is insane. I'll try to work on this proof again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show (a), argue by contraposition. Without the loss of generality, assume that $A_1, A_2$ are closed and $A_1$ is disconnected. Here using the fact that $A_1$ is closed, there has to exist an open interval with positive length $(a,b) \subset  {A_1}^c$ such that the end points $a$ and $b$ are contained in $A_1$.

Now  if  $A_1\cup A_2$ is connected, then $(a,b)\subset A_2$. Using the fact that $A_2$ is also closed, the end points $a,b\in A_2$ as well. However $A_1\cap A_2$ would be disconnected since $a,b\in  A_1\cap A_2$ but $(A_1\cap A_2)\cap(a,b) = \emptyset$.

Thus $A_1\cup A_2$ and $A_1\cap A_2$ can not be both connected.